# write to a database in Activity A so that Activity B can read it

Tags: android

In android, if you want to write to a database in Activity A so that Activity B can read it, should you 
write to the database in onPause, onStop, or either method?

Comment: As long as it's written before Activity B starts, it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better idea is to store that data just before firing `Intent` which starts Activity B.